# GIT push on Google Appengine

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I am looking at setting up a remote depository so I can use git push to upload my application.

First issue I have is saving my password in the .netrc file. Am I missing something or is this very insecure? I don't want to upload this to github with my password there!

Second issue I have is being able to upload multiple branches. 
Say I have 2 branches: master and develop. Would it be possible to push them up as separate versions to:

```
https://myapplication.com/
```

and

```
https://develop-dot-myapplication.com/
```

I know the docs say you can only upload the master branch, but I was wondering if anyone knows a good work around.

Many thanks.

Comment: you can do it like that for different versions, but numbers only IIRC.  1.myapp, 2.myapp. Perhaps that's your workaround.